# STL set of map iterators

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator, set

I have an stl unordered_map and I would like to store references to elements in that map.  I would like there to be no duplicate references.  I thought I could create an set of iterators which pointed to elements.  For one I wasn't sure that it would recognise , but even so I got some long template errors which I think boiled down to there being no comparison operator < for iterators.

I then tried an unordered set compiling with g++ -std=c++0x but got pages of errors.

How can I achieve this goal?

```
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {

  typedef std::unordered_map<int, float> umap;
  umap my_map;

  umap::const_iterator itr;
  for (int i=0;i<10000000;i++) {
    my_map[i] = float(i);
  }

 umap::iterator my_it1 = my_map.find(43);
 umap::iterator my_it2 = my_map.find(44);
 umap::iterator my_it3 = my_map.find(44);


 std::unordered_set<umap::iterator> my_its;
 my_its.insert(my_it1); 
 my_its.insert(my_it2);
 my_its.insert(my_it3);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to store the iterators in an unordered set, you don't need a comparison operator but rather a hash function.

I'm guessing, since each distinct iterator will be pointing to a distinct key, you can use the hash value of the key for hashing the iterator.

```
struct iterator_hash
{
    size_t operator()(std::unordered_map<int, float>::const_iterator it) const 
    { 
        return std::hash<int>()(it->first); 
    }
};
```

and instantiate the unordered set as:

```
std::unordered_set<umap::iterator, iterator_hash> my_its;
```

`unordered_set` also requires an equality function, but the iterators own `operator==` should do fine, as long as all the iterators belong to the same `unordered_map`.

Careful with iterator invalidation.

Comment: Great this compiles.  Coming to think of it.  There are lot of useful set algorithms like intersection that I can use directly and simply with a normal set.  Is there an arbitrary comparison function I can implement so that I can utilise these without actually caring about the ordering.